# SQL search query with multiple criteria

Tags: mysql, sql

I don't know what to call this problem, that's why I need your help:)

I want to search my query with these parameters:

```
int2
4
5
```

What I want to get is:

```
int1
1
2
```

i dont want to get this:

```
int1
3
```

Table:

```
+------+------+
|int1  |int2  |
+------+------+
|1     |4     |
+------+------+
|1     |5     |
+------+------+
|1     |6     |
+------+------+
|2     |4     |
+------+------+
|2     |5     |
+------+------+
|3     |4     |
+------+------+
|3     |6     |
+------+------+
```

i want to get all int1 which have 4 and 5 in any row.

thank you:)

Answer (score 2):

A solution is to use a subquery like:

```
select t1.int1
from yourtable t1
inner join 
  (select int1 
  from yourtable
  where int2 = 4) t2 on t1.int1 = t2.int1
where t1.int2 = 5
```

Comment: thank you! where does t2 come from? and what if i would have more criteria for int2? like i need the int1 with int2=3 and int2=4 and int2=5 and so on